# Como fazer um `select multiple` iniciar com a primeira opção já marcada PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, formulário

Segue meu componente:

```
       $query_menu = mysql_query("SELECT 
       rm_id     AS FUNCAO,
       rm_desc   AS DESCRICAO,
       rm_obs    AS OBSERVACAO,
       rm_status AS STATUS 
            FROM radios_menu 
                 WHERE rm_status='0'");

echo"<div class='form-group'>";
  echo"<div class='col-lg-12'>";
    echo"<select multiple='' id='v_desc' name='v_desc' class='form-control'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_menu)){
         $v_funcao    = $row["FUNCAO"];
         $v_desc      = $row["DESCRICAO"];
         $v_obs       = $row["OBSERVACAO"];
         $v_status    = $row["STATUS"];
    echo"<option value='$v_funcao'>$v_desc</option>"; 
         }
    echo"</select>";
  echo"</div>";
echo"</div>";
```

Com ajuda de @caiocafardo deu certo, mais na estilização ficou só uma coisa que gostaria de mudar:
 Meu item escolhido fica de azul:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mais o do @caiocafardo fica cinza:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia fazer para os dois ficarem azul ? 
 Estou usando o bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só checar se é a primeira passagem pelo WHILE:

```
$checaPrimeiro = 1;
$checaSeleciona = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_menu)){
    $v_funcao    = $row["FUNCAO"];
    $v_desc      = $row["DESCRICAO"];
    $v_obs       = $row["OBSERVACAO"];
    $v_status    = $row["STATUS"];
    //
    if($checaPrimeiro == 1){
        $checaSeleciona = "selected";
    }else{
        $checaSeleciona = "";
    }
    echo "<option value='$v_funcao' $checaSeleciona>$v_desc</option>"; 
    $checaPrimeiro++;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito,deu certo,mais veja se pode me ajudar na estilização,complementei na pergunta.

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa isso deve te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346956/how-to-change-bootstrap-3-selected-option-background-color